# Shell Script Syntax Error if [[ $Char == [A-Z] -o $Char == [a-z] ]]

Tags: shell, unix, syntax-error

In the below mentioned code the line
if [[ $Char == [A-Z] -o $Char == [a-z] ]]
shows the following error

symbol.sh: line 2: syntax error in conditional expression

symbol.sh: line 2: syntax error near `-o'

```
read -p "Enter the Character " Char
if [[ $Char == [A-Z] -o $Char == [a-z] ]] 
then 
    echo "The Character entered is an ALPHABET"
elif [[ $Char == [0-9] ]]
then
    echo "The Character entered is a NUMBER"
else
    echo "The Character entered is a Special Symbol"    
fi
```

I tried doing it the other way and it works fine.

```
read -p "Enter the Character " Char
if [[ $Char == [a-z] ]] 
then 
    echo "The Character entered is an ALPHABET"
elif [[ $Char == [A-Z] ]] 
then 
    echo "The Character entered is an ALPHABET"
elif [[ $Char == [0-9] ]]
then
    echo "The Character entered is a NUMBER"
else
    echo "The Character entered is a Special Symbol"    
fi
```

I just want to know what is wrong with this line of code
**if [[ $Char == [A-Z] -o $Char == [a-z] ]]**

Comment: The construct `[[` does not exist in POSIX shell.

Comment: See [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#top) page which explains, how to write tests in a POSIX shell.

Comment: You can use zsh or ksh or bash to use `[[`, but in this case, the _or_ condition would be written as `||` and not as `-o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up the syntax for the various comparison operators. The `test` (or `[`) command *does* use the `-o` syntax to be an "or" operator, but [the `[[` conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) has a different syntax; there, `-o` checks to see if the given shell option is enabled. To get an "or" with `[[`, use the `||` syntax between tests:

```sh
if [[ $Char == [A-Z] ]] || [[ $Char == [a-z] ]] 
then 
# ...
```

You could alternatively use the bash syntax that tests against your locale's character classes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the Character " Char
if [[ $Char == [[:alpha:]] ]]
then
    echo "The Character entered is an ALPHABET"
elif [[ $Char == [[:digit:]] ]]
then
    echo "The Character entered is a NUMBER"
else
    echo "The Character entered is a Special Symbol"
fi
```